# Magento 2.2.6 - Change the product name title

Tags: magento2, product, module, layout, template

how I can change products name attribute. I create a new attribute `second_name` and I assigned to all products, now I want this attribute to replace the default `name` attribute. I need to change this on products view page.

I try to add something like this but is not working:

```
   namespace Company\Module\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $registry;

        public function __construct
        (
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
        ) {
            $this->registry = $registry;
        }

        public function getTitle()
        {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
            $title = $this->product->getAttributeText('second_name');
            return $title;
        }
    }
```

and I add this code in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Data::getTitle"></argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

So in product view page instead Product Name I need to be my custom attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can suggest solving your problem. You should create a custom module and then use Plugin as following steps:

> 1. app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="training_catalog_product" type="Company\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/Company/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $title = $subject->getAttributeText('second_name');
        return $title;
    }
}
```

You can try these steps and let me know your result.

Comment: How can we do without plugin ?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this without a plugin. This is very straightforward and works perfectly!